# strtotime data value example

Tags: php, facebook

I can't believe I'm posting this question. I'm reading the facebook api docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading

Under Time-based Pagination it states:

> A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the end of the
>   range of time-based data.

I'm well aware of unix timestamp, however how does a `strtotime` value look like? `2016-10-01`? `Wednesday 9th October`? I can't find any simle examples, not even on phps website.

Comment: Check here to see how `strtotime` is being used in php. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: I dont totally understand the question. A simple test `echo strtotime('2016-10-01');` gives `1475280000` would show you an example. So there must be more to this question than meets the eye

Comment: What the documentation says here, is that you can basically pass any value that `strtotime` “understands”. And the PHP manual page for that function explicitly mentions http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php